# Batch editing the end of unique lines in a text file

Tags: file, batch-file, text, unique, editing

Current text file looks like this:

```
File1=vhm47
Title1=asdffsag
Length1=3677
File2=d1536
Title2=fasgasgf
Length2=342
File3=vhm46
Title3=gdsafhhds
Length3=3601
File4=d1452
```

I need to add ".enc" to the end of every File line. But I cannot batch edit because each file line contains a unique number. There's anywhere from 150 to 700 files at a time.

Comment: Did you forget to post the code that you've written to perform this task, but which is failing  to do so? I would suggest that you do that, because in its current state, your question looks like an off topic code request. Please ensure that you've taken the [tour] and both read and understood [ask], including each of its linked pages.

Comment: Simple using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl "^File.*" "$&.enc" /f "yourFile.txt" /o -`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "FILE_=.\info.txt"
set "NEW_FILE=.\info2.txt"
set "toContain=File"
set "toAdd=.enc"

break>"%NEW_FILE%"
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%FILE_%") do (
    set line=%%a
    if "!line:%toContain%=!" EQU "!line!" (
        (echo(!line!)>>"%NEW_FILE%"
    ) else (
        (echo(!line!%toAdd%)>>"%NEW_FILE%"
    )
)
```

At the beginning set the correct path to your file and the path to the new file where the extension will be added